# R markdown link is not formatted blue when knitted to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown

for some reason no link in my R markdowns (rmd) is formatted blue. knitting the simple rmd below to pdf is leaving the text color black. only when hovering over it does one realize that it's actually a link. knitting it to html will make the link blue. of course I can use a latex wrapper but I wonder why that is?

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>   loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    knitr_1.15

RStudio 1.0.44

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---

```{r, echo=F}
# tex / pandoc options for pdf creation
x <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
y <- paste(x, "E:\\miktex\\miktex\\bin", sep=";")
Sys.setenv(PATH = y)
```

[link](www.rstudio.com)
````

[image]

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Add `urlcolor: blue` to the yaml.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_notebook: default
urlcolor: blue
---

```{r, echo=F}
# tex / pandoc options for pdf creation
x <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
y <- paste(x, "E:\\miktex\\miktex\\bin", sep=";")
Sys.setenv(PATH = y)
```

[Link to R Studio](www.rstudio.com)

Bare urls will also be highlighted:

http://www.rstudio.com
````

[image]

Comment: Interestingly it works like a breeze, but even though I specify blue my links become red.  Any idea why? Standard pandoc layout perhaps?

Comment: I got the same issue using bookdown when exporting to PDF (using `pdf_document2`). Interestingly, they are blue when I export to a docx using `word_document2`

Answer (score 29):

To elaborate on the answer by @eipi10, and to answer a question in the comments by @Maarten Punt, the `urlcolor` is specifying the color for URL links referenced in the doc. However you might have links to other sections in your document, specified by `linkcolor`. So you can specify either:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document: default
urlcolor: blue
linkcolor: red
---

## test links vs urls

* see [the relevant section](#test)



[link](http://www.rstudio.com)


```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\newpage

## Including Plots{#test}

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image]

The red is a link within the document, whereas the blue is a URL link.