# Why can't I get colors of code in an R Markdown document to print?

Tags: html, colors, rstudio, r-markdown

When I create an R Markdown notebook in RStudio, the code chunks do all the usual text coloring of RStudio -- for example, comment lines and text constants in green, numerical constants in blue, etc.  All the coloring still shows up nicely when I open RStudio's HTML preview window, and equally well when I view the HTML document in a browser.

Colors embedded in ggplot2 graphics objects in the same document are appearing equally successfully, up to this point (on-screen viewing of HTML).

However, when I send the HTML document to a printer from my Mac's browser, or when I use the Print dialog to export the HTML doc to PDF, all the text coloring disappears and everything is rendered in black text, even as the ggplot2 graphics colors are still completely successful in the printed output.

How can I recover the text coloring in printed output?  Thanks.

(This is happening on a Mac laptop, just the same in Firefox and Safari.)

---

Editing 1 day later to add:
there's a symptom I hadn't noticed until after I applied @user2554330's initial solution.  Hyperlinks in the markdown text (i.e., outside code chunks) get transformed into black text as well, and both the link text and the underlying URL get printed, unlike in the HTML output which is in color and shows only the text of the link.

I tried `.hljs-link` based on what I found at https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/css-classes-reference.html, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to fix.

The problem is that `rmarkdown` uses the `bootstrap` framework to set styles.  That framework tries to standardize the display on different browsers; since browsers are really variable in how they handle printing, it chooses a very simple black on white style for printing text.

You can create a CSS file that overrides these choices, or you can edit the source to the `bootstrap` CSS file so that it doesn't do that.  Both are hard.

The problem with creating your own CSS file is that you need to re-specify the colors for each different type of text, marking all of the choices as `!important`.   `rmarkdown` has several different color schemes for highlighting code.  The default one looks like this after editing:

```
.hljs-literal {
  color: #990073!important;
}

.hljs-number {
  color: #099!important;
}

.hljs-comment {
  color: #998!important;
  font-style: italic;
}

.hljs-keyword {
  color: #900!important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hljs-string {
  color: #d14!important;
}
```

If you're using a different highlight style, you'll need to edit that one instead.

Save this in a file, e.g. `style.css`, then put this in your YAML header:

```
output: 
  html_document:
    css: style.css
```

The alternative to this is to edit the `bootstrap` source so that it no longer forces the color to black.   Look for the `@media print` sections, and edit those.  The file to edit is

```
<rmarkdown dir>/rmd/h/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

(which is a minimized version of `bootstrap.css`, so it's hard to edit).

If you really know what you're doing, you can recompile the file with different options; I haven't tried that.

EDITED TO ADD:

If you also want URLs to appear in color, you'll need to do something similar for them:  override the override.  A simple version is

```
a {
  color: #23527c!important;  
}
```

which forces all links to be blueish.  This isn't ideal; it doesn't let links change color when selected, so the original on-screen version of your document will be changed, not just the print version.  I'm too lazy right now to figure out how to handle the color change.

To stop the URL from being appended, you want this text:

```
a[href]::after {
  content: "";
}
```

This says that anchors with HREF elements should get an empty string appended.  The standard `bootstrap` spec appends the extra text that you saw.  This doesn't appear to need `!important`, since the standard one didn't use that.

Put both of these entries into your `style.css` file, and you should get your links in color when printing, without appending the URL.

Comment: That works nicely, thanks.  Pleasant color choices, too.  I'll add that `html_notebook` seems to work in the YAML header equally as well as `html_document`, and I find the former more congenial when working in RStudio.

Comment: I've edited the question to expand the question slightly, on a point that seems to need a separate repair:  hyperlinks also print badly.

Comment: And again, thanks for the additional information about handling the hyperlinks -- works great.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question, while also checking out other relevant answers, so I think [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895870/) fixes your hyperlink problem. TLDR: Add `urlcolor: blue` and possibly `linkcolor:red` to the documents yaml section at the top :)