# Change the color of embedded hyperlink in Rmarkdown (Slidy)

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, slidy

This is a slidy_presentation in R, and I want my embedded hyperlink to be red in color instead of black, so that the user knows that the word "help" is clickable.

I have referred to this post to include `linkcolor: red`, but it doesn't work, I'm not sure why.
[R markdown link is not formatted blue when knitted to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892802/r-markdown-link-is-not-formatted-blue-when-knitted-to-pdf)

My code:

```
---
title: "XXX" 
subtitle: "XXX" 
author: 
- "XXX"
date: "Last updated: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    font_adjustment: -2
    highlight: haddock
    mathjax: "default"
    df_print: paged
citecolor: red 
linkcolor: red
urlcolor: blue
---
```

Embedded hyperlink code:

```
[help](https://www.aihw.gov.au/suicide-self-harm-monitoring/research-information/crisis-support) is always available.
```

R Slidy output: the "help" word does not appear as red color.

[image]

Comment: In the Beamer works right. You want only in Slidy?

Comment: No worries, I've figured out how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution for this.

`[<span style="color: red">**HELP**</span>](https://www.aihw.gov.au/suicide-self-harm-monitoring/research-information/crisis-support)`

Output:

> [image]

Comment: But this highlights only one single single link. I would prefer to change it in the CSS.