# How can I modify the color of cross-referencing in the R markdown generated pdf document?

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, cross-reference

````
---
title: "Annual Report"
author: "Xyz"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(),'%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    linkcolor: blue

---


```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
names(mtcars)
```
### Heading 1
```{r figure-1,echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Sample Graph 1"}
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=hp))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_classic()

```


To see another graph, please see figure \textcolor{blue}{\@ref(fig:figure-2)}

\newpage
### Heading 2
```{r figure-2,echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Sample Graph 2"}
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=carb))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_classic()

```


To see another graph, please see figure \@ref(fig:figure-1)
````

After execution, I found the following in knitted pdf document before **Heading 2**.

*To see another graph, please see figure reffig:figure-2*

*reffig:figure* in the code is not cross-referenced as well. What I want is that my document should show the following line in the pdf document:

**To see another graph, please see figure 2**

"2" in the above statement should be hyperlinked and its color should be blue, enabling the reader to jump to figure 2 if user clicks on "2".

Answer (score 0):

Adding `urlcolor:blue` to your yaml should work.

```
---
title: "Annual Report"
author: "Xyz"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(),'%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    linkcolor: blue

urlcolor: blue
---
```

Original answer found here: [R markdown link is not formatted blue when knitted to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40892802)